# Laravel resource store method is being redirected to destroy method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a resource route

`Route::resource('climb-excluded','CexcludedController',['only'=>['store','update','destroy']]);`

And my code in view to save data

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('climb-excluded.store') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-head style-primary">
        <header>Add item</header>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body floating-label">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <button type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-block btn-success ink-reaction">
                    Add
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A button to destroy data:

```
{!!  Form::open( array('route'=>array('climb-excluded.destroy', $excluded->id),
'method'=>'DELETE')) !!}
<button type="submit"
    class="btn ink-reaction btn-floating-action btn-sm btn-danger "
    rel="tooltip"
    title="Delete">
<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Store method form controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required|max:255'
    ]);

    $excluded = new Cexcluded;
    $excluded -> name = $request->name;
    $excluded->save();
    //redirect to
    Session::flash('success','New item sucessfully added !');
    return back()->withInput(['tabs'=>'second4']);
}
```

Destroy method form controller:

```
    public function destroy($id)
{
    $trekExcluded = Cexcluded::find($id);
    $trekExcluded->tours()->detach();
    $trekExcluded ->delete();
    Session::flash('success','Item sucessfully deleted !');
    return back()->withInput(['tabs'=>'second4']);
}
```

The trouble/bug that I'm facing is I can insert first row into table successfully. But when I go for the second one, the store method is somehow redirected to  destroy method and deletes the first inserted row also. While I've clearly declared store method in action attribute of the form.

FYI: Both routes exists in same view/page. Destroy method in `col-md-8`with `foreach` loop while store method in `col-md-4`

Answer (score 0):

Its quite obvious, that your form don't have a unique `name` or `id`, so that's why the second method is redirected to destroy method. Do something like this:

```
cex-store-1
cex-destroy-1
```

Comment: You mean add `id` attribute to form ??

Comment: Yes. But remember that you need to write JS to trigger destroy form

Comment: I want to accomplish this task without js

Comment: I would rather do it through JS. That way i don't have to put in a submit button for my destroy form.